# Create decile data for multiple years in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this in R:

```
SchoolName  Year  Grade  Other_cols_not_of_interest
School1     1998  152
School2     1998  156
School3     1999  158
```

For each of the years 1998-2011 I'd like to calculate the deciles for the *available* school data. (For one year, there may be data for 40 schools and for another just 20.)

This is the output I'd like to see:

```
Decile  Year   Value
D1      1998   100
D2      1998   110
D3      1998   125
[...]
D10     1998   170
D1      1999   105
[...]
```

Comment: Are you looking for decile boundaries? If so, there are nine.

Comment: You can `tapply` the `quantile` function

Comment: Thank you @Henry. I think I'm looking for the decile mean and not the boundaries ...? I'd like to be able to say "The average of the 10% lowest performing schools have had this development over time ..." etc. Can I still use tapply and with what modification? Can you briefly describe the difference between Decile and Decile boundary? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
schoolDat <- data.frame(
  'SchoolName' = rep(paste('School',1:10), each=10),
  'Year' = rep(1998:2007, 10),
  'Grade' = rpois(100, 100)
  )


tapply(schoolDat$Grade, schoolDat$Year, quantile, probs=0:10/10)
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this give the mean of each quantile or does it give the actual points 0%, 10%, ... 100%?

Comment: Mean of each quantile? No, they are statistics computed empirically at the school level for every year. If you wanted to collapse across year giving the mean decile, then you'd want to reshape the data a bit.

Try:


`o <- tapply(schoolDat$Grade, schoolDat$Year, quantile, probs=0:10/10)`


`rowMeans(sapply(o, identity))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is version using the `plyr` package that will return the results in a dataframe with 3 columns.

```
dat <- data.frame('SchoolName' = rep(paste('School', 1:10), each=10),
              'Year' = rep(1998:2007, 10),
              'Grade' = rpois(100, 100))

require(plyr)
d <- ddply(dat, .(Year), summarise, decile_grade=quantile(Grade, 0:10/10), 
       decile_val=0:10/10)

head(d)
>   Year decile_grade decile_val
  1 1998         81.0        0.0
  2 1998         90.0        0.1
  3 1998         93.4        0.2
  4 1998        100.3        0.3
  5 1998        104.8        0.4
  6 1998        106.5        0.5
```

Comment: Thank you. The code seems to render 11 groups? I'd preferably like to generate the Mean of 10 groups. How can I modify the code?

Comment: Do you want to exlcude the 0th percentile or the 100th percentile?

Comment: I'd like to group the data in to 10 groups and then take the mean in every group so that I can show how the average of the 10% schools with lowest performance compare with other groups, say the: 50-60% group or the 90-100% group. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the mean of every decile?

Comment: I think so yes. Group each year's schools into 10 groups and then take the mean of each group.

Comment: You should really provide a sample of your data and some expected output.

Comment: Suppose I have 50 schools year 1998. I want to be able to state that the 10% lowest performing (i.e. that bottom 5 schools) have an average value of X. The next group, i.e. group 6-10 have an average of Y and so on up to the tenth group comprising schools 46-50. Perhaps I can just as well use p5, p15, p25, ... p95?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3241/discussion-between-idris-and-dani)